# Can't retrieve extra data in new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

I have implemented Parcelable into an Object I want to pass between activities when I click on a CardView inside a Recycler View. The only problem is the object (ResultsHelperClass) always has modified values upon receiving the intent.

I'm completely stuck at the moment as I can't seem to find the problem.

The object I pass into the intent as an extra has the correct values, but no matter how I try to receive it it always has the values changed.

My ResultsHelperClass

```
public class ResultsHelperClass implements Parcelable {

    int  localScore, visitorScore, teamId;
    String teamName, localLogoUrl, visitorLogoUrl, local, date;

      //Constructor
public ResultsHelperClass(String localLogoUrl, String visitorLogoUrl, String local, String date, int teamId, int localScore, int visitorScore, String teamName) {
    this.localScore = localScore;
    this.visitorScore = visitorScore;
    this.teamName = teamName;
    this.teamId = teamId;
    this.localLogoUrl = localLogoUrl;
    this.visitorLogoUrl = visitorLogoUrl;
    this.local = local;
    this.date = date;
}

    //Constructor
    public ResultsHelperClass() {
        this.localScore = 0;
    this.visitorScore = 0;
    this.teamId = 0;
    this.teamName = "";
    this.localLogoUrl = "";
    this.visitorLogoUrl = "";
    this.local = "";
    this.date = "";
    }

    protected ResultsHelperClass(Parcel in) {
        localScore = in.readInt();
        visitorScore = in.readInt();
        teamId = in.readInt();
        teamName = in.readString();
        localLogoUrl = in.readString();
        visitorLogoUrl = in.readString();
        local = in.readString();
        date = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<ResultsHelperClass> CREATOR = new Creator<ResultsHelperClass>() {
        @Override
        public ResultsHelperClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ResultsHelperClass(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ResultsHelperClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ResultsHelperClass[size];
        }
    };

    //Getters
    public int getLocalScore() {
        return localScore;
    }

    public int getVisitorScore() {
        return visitorScore;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public int getTeamId() {
        return teamId;
    }


    public String getLocal() {
        return local;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getLocalLogoUrl() {
        return localLogoUrl;
    }

    public String getVisitorLogoUrl() {
        return visitorLogoUrl;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setLocalScore(int localScore) {
        this.localScore = localScore;
    }

    public void setVisitorScore(int visitorScore) {
        this.visitorScore = visitorScore;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamId(int teamId) {
        this.teamId = teamId;
    }

    public void setLocalLogoUrl(String localLogoUrl) {
        this.localLogoUrl = localLogoUrl;
    }

    public void setVisitorLogoUrl(String visitorLogoUrl) {
        this.visitorLogoUrl = visitorLogoUrl;
    }

    public void setLocal(String local) {
        this.local = local;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(teamName);
        dest.writeString(localLogoUrl);
        dest.writeString(visitorLogoUrl);
        dest.writeString(local);
        dest.writeString(date);
        dest.writeInt(localScore);
        dest.writeInt(visitorScore);
        dest.writeInt(teamId);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ResultsHelperClass{" +
                "localScore=" + localScore +
                ", visitorScore=" + visitorScore +
                ", teamId=" + teamId +
                ", teamName='" + teamName + '\'' +
                ", localLogoUrl='" + localLogoUrl + '\'' +
                ", visitorLogoUrl='" + visitorLogoUrl + '\'' +
                ", local='" + local + '\'' +
                ", date='" + date + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I print the item selected before sending it to the Extra intent:

```
@Override
    public void onGameClick(int position) {

        Intent in = new Intent(this, Team.class);
        System.out.println(listResults.get(position));
        in.putExtra("game", listResults.get(position));
        startActivity(in);
    }
```

This prints the correct values for the selected item:

I/System.out: ResultsHelperClass{localScore=0, visitorScore=0, teamId=1, teamName='Sénior Masculí ', localLogoUrl='https://pitudev.com/sacabaneta/rivals/sacabaneta.jpg', visitorLogoUrl='https://www.pitudev.com/sacabaneta/rivals/sonservera.jpg', local='1', date='2020-08-16 18:30:00.000000'

In the new activity (Team), i do this to retrieve the data from the selected item:

if (getIntent().hasExtra("game")){

```
    ResultsHelperClass selected_game = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("game");
    System.out.println(selected_game);
```

}

This prints these values:

I/System.out: ResultsHelperClass{localScore=15, visitorScore=15269971, teamId=6881390, teamName='null', localLogoUrl='null', visitorLogoUrl='null', local='null', date='null'}

This makes no sense to me since I have checked that i pass the correct values... I would be so grateful if someone could help... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed...

The problem was that writeToParcel() and ResultsHelperClass(Parcel in) properties need to be in the same order...

Hope this helps someone in the future!